# show/hide row on hovering column other row with universal(dynamic) code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a web page I have five columns inside a row(`.toplvl`). Each has their own class like `.tli-1, .tli-2, .tli-3, .tli-4, .tli-5`

So column three has the class `.tli-3`

Below the `.toplvl` row I have 5 more rows which are called `.tlcr-1, .tlcr-2, .tlcr-3, .tlcr-4, .tlcr-5`

So row three has the class `.tlcr-3`

**What do I want to achieve**

When hovering over `.tli-1` it should display `.tlcr-1` and stay open as long as the mousepointer is on either `.tli-1` or `.tlcr-1`

This same logic goes for all the other columns.

**It needs to be dynamic**

The amount of columns and rows can differ. At one time it can be 3 but it could also be 50. The classes will remain the same apart from the number part. If their where for instance 50 then the last column would be called `.tli-50` and the last row `tlcr-50`

**My current code**

Which works but needs me to duplicate it for over 50 times and manually changing the numbers. There must be a better way for this.

```
$( ".tli-2" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $( ".tlcr-2" ).css('display', 'block');
})
$( ".tli-2" ).mouseleave(function() {
  $( ".tlcr-2" ).mouseenter(function() {
      $( ".tlcr-2" ).css('display', 'block');
      $( ".tlcr-2" ).mouseleave(function() {
        $( ".tlcr-2" ).css('display', 'none');
      })
  })
  $( ".tlcr-2" ).css('display', 'none');
});
```

**A Fiddle for better understanding of the structure**

https://jsfiddle.net/3naxLfm6/

**Thanks for helping**

Everyone who is going to reply. Thank you very much for taking the time. I would really appreciate a solution with a working fiddle but off course is any suggestion absolutely welcome. Furthermore, if anything is unclear about the question please allow me to make it better before down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have some things you can do.

1. Listen once for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`
2. On mouse enter, first, [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) all the rows. Then, get the hovered item's [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) the corresponding (by [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)) row.

```js
$('.column').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('.tlcr').hide();
  const index = $(this).index('.column');
  $('.tlcr').eq(index).show();
});
```

```css
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width:100%;
  min-height:50px;
}
.tlcr {
  display: none;
}
.column {
  text-align:center;
}
.w20 {
  width:20%;
}
.tli-1, .tlcr-1 {background:red;}
.tli-2, .tlcr-2 {background:blue;}
.tli-3, .tlcr-3 {background:green;}
.tli-4, .tlcr-4 {background:purple;}
.tli-5, .tlcr-5 {background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row toplvl">
  <div class="column w20 tli-1">Item 1</div> 
  <div class="column w20 tli-2">Item 2</div> 
  <div class="column w20 tli-3">Item 3</div> 
  <div class="column w20 tli-4">Item 4</div> 
  <div class="column w20 tli-5">Item 5</div> 
</div>
<div class="row tlcr tlcr-1">Content 1</div>
<div class="row tlcr tlcr-2">Content 2</div>
<div class="row tlcr tlcr-3">Content 3</div>
<div class="row tlcr tlcr-4">Content 4</div>
<div class="row tlcr tlcr-5">Content 5</div>
```

Comment: Yes absolutely beautiful, Accepted as it works right out of the box. Thank you so much! I am going to study up about the index, and I am really glad you put in links everywhere for people to do the studying.

Comment: I am so sorry I was too quick with accepting. Because your fiddle is doing the same thing as on the website. It does not allow the hover over the rows. The moment the mouse leaves the column it removes the row from view. How to adapt your code to allow for the same behaviour as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/aLquks1c/1/

Comment: @purple11111 what do you think? Seems like it much simpler than I thought..

Answer (score 0):

First a big shout out to @MoshFeu for posting the partially good answer. Now keep in mind his answer is clear and very informative and should receive all the up votes it deserves. Without it, I wouldn't have been able to make it work for my specific scenario.

I modified his code to achieve the effect needed and here is this modified code and the corresponding fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/djwx5k1g/

```
$('.tli')
  .on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $('.tlcr').hide();
      const index = $(this).index('.tli');
      $('.tlcr').eq(index).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $('.tlcr').eq(index)
        .on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            $('.tlcr').eq(index).show();
          }
        });
    }
  });
  $('.tlcr')
    .on({
      mouseleave: function() {
        $('.tlcr').hide();
      }
    });
```